# Connect to putty and type few command

Tags: python, putty

I want to connect to putty and want to do few step:

1. login to Putty
2. type few command to bring down the server
3. Traverse to the particular path
4. Remove the file from the directory
5. Again start the server

I need to write the code in windows. But my server is in linux.
How shall I proceed?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [Fabric](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/1.3.1) to do these steps.

Comment: I think you want a login to an SSH Server, so you can use http://www.lag.net/paramiko/. You won't need PuTTY!

Answer (score 9):

What you need is **[Paramiko](https://github.com/robey/paramiko)**, but it may be a little complicated for a beginner.

For simple, repetitive tasks you may **use my script** - it is [located on GitHub (https://github.com/tadeck/ssh-matic)](https://github.com/tadeck/ssh-matic) and was created to learn some Python. It is based on someone else's **friendly SSH Python interface** to Paramiko ([code accessible here](https://github.com/tadeck/ssh-matic/blob/master/ssh/__init__.py)).

Using the mentioned SSH module connecting to server and executing a command is rather simple:

```
import ssh
server = ssh.Connection(host='host', username='user', private_key='key_path')
result = server.execute('your command')
```

Basically what you need is not PuTTy, but a SSH module to Python. This module should work both on Windows and Linux. Using my script you will only need to work on the command you want to invoke, plus adjust the code to your needs.

Good luck. Tell me if it helped.

Comment: Can you upload the module to PyPi please?

Comment: Link to Paramiko is dead.

Comment: Can you include the link to "...someone else's **friendly SSH Python interface**..."?

Answer (score 5):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application ().Start (cmd_line=u'putty -ssh user_name@10.70.15.175')
putty = app.PuTTY
putty.Wait ('ready')
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("password")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("ls")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

I am using python 2.7. Code is running on Windows, and connect to remote Linux. it is working in my environment.

Comment: Can you suggest a workaround to make it wait until a complex process like rsync is over, and then execute other commands,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
# Use plink to open a connection to the remote shell
command = "plink.exe -ssh %s -batch" % credentials
sp = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Send commands to the shell as if they were read from a shell script
sp.stdin.write("command1\n")
sp.stdin.write("command2\n")
sp.stdin.close()
# read out the answers, if needed
ans = sp.stdout.read()
sp.wait()
```

For `credentials`, it is best to put the name of a PuTTY connection profile, ready with the username set and a SSH key.

Answer (score 3):

you can use code similar to:

`command = "plink.exe -ssh username@" + hostname + " -pw password -batch \"export DISPLAY='" + hostname + "/unix:0.0' ; "`

which will open an ssh to the desired `hostname` using `username` and `password`

shutdown:
`command += "sudo /sbin/halt\""`

reboot:
`command += "sudo /sbin/reboot\""`

add your other commands using the same method as above,

run the command with:

`pid = subprocess.Popen(command).pid`

As pointed out by Tadeck, this will only work on a windows machine attempting to connect to a linux machine.

Comment: Of course your solution is totally platform-dependent, and will only work on Windows connecting to Linux/Unix system.

Comment: indeed it is, but that is what the OP wanted, and what I did very recently.

Comment: @Tadeck, thank you, I should have mentioned what you said, it was an oversight on my part, I'll add it for correctness.